# program that generates addition problems randomly and displays them to the user

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that generates random numbers, asks user to guess addition output and when the user fails to guess output correctly then it should print the total number of guesses performed.
my code is as follows. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
from random import randint
a = randint(0,100)
b = randint(1,100)
c=raw_input(" enter your answer ") 
    for i in range(10):
        print  a,'+',b,'=', c
    print('Correct!\n') #if answer is correct
elif
    print ('Correct Solutions!' (i))
```

Comment: If you are encountering an issue with your code, you should describe the issue and _ask_ for help, not `correct my code asap`

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not a free homework completion service. You need to learn to program yourself, not ask internet strangers to program for you.

Comment: ok. Any help? or advice !!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code *and* accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Specifically, what is wrong with your current code?  What have to done to attack that problem?  The code you posted shows a lack of sequential planning.

Comment: I'm trying to code a program that generates addition problems randomly and displays them to the user. The user then attempts to solve the problem. Once the user has entered an incorrect solution print the number of correct solutions.

Example Input/Output 
93+60=153 
Correct! 
55+16=71 
Correct! 
37+11=48 
Correct! 
57+96=151 
Correct Solutions: 3

Answer (score 0):

For one, your indentation is messed up. And you seem to have multiple different versions of python code- `print()` as a function is python3, `print` as a statement is python2. Also python3 uses `input()` instead of `raw_input()`. In this answer, I'll be assuming python3 and this indentation model:

```
from random import randint
a = randint(0,100)
b = randint(1,100)
c = input(" enter your answer ") 
for i in range(10):
    print( a,'+',b,'=', c)
    print('Correct!\n') #if answer is correct
    elif
        print ('Correct Solutions!' (i))
```

For one, `elif` requires there to be an `if` before it. I assume this should be something like

```
if (a+b) == int(c): 
    print("Correct")
```

Then the next one should be `else`, since the answer is either correct or it's not.

Next, you only get input once, before you loop. Since we're in the loop, we'll address that too- for loops are bounded, they only go X times and no more. What happens when the person is really bad and answers wrongly 12 times? They don't ever get it correct, since the loop completed. Rewrite it as a `while` loop:

```
count=0 # no correct answers yet
while True: # Keep going until they're right
    # Edits as per comments:
    a = random.randint(0,100)
    b = random.randint(0,100)
    # end edits.
    c = input((str(a)+' + '+str(b)+' = '))
    # Check if correct
    if (a+b) == int(c):
        print("Correct!")
        count += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
        break # stop when they get one wrong
```

Also, input always comes in as a string- you have to coerce it into a numerical value.

EDIT: added a few lines as per comments.

Comment: I'm trying to code a program that generates addition problems randomly and displays them to the user. The user then attempts to solve the problem. Once the user has entered an incorrect solution print the number of correct solutions.

Comment: Example Input/Output
93+60=153
Correct!
55+16=71
Correct!
37+11=48
Correct!
57+96=151
Correct Solutions: 3

Comment: So most of your code has to be in a while loop- for every loop, you'll want to generate numbers, display the problem, get input, check correctness. If it's correct, you'll need to increment a counter; otherwise you'll break from the loop and print the number of corrects. Code edited to show- you'll have to add the ending print statement.

Comment: One problem i'm facing from the beginning is, the system has to display the addition operation on executing. for example, 20+30=ask user to enter answer[user input]

Comment: instead our code asks the answer first and later tells us question.

Comment: So rearrange things? You can actually use the input prompt to print things how you want, i.e. `c = input(str(a) + '+' + str(b) + '= ')` will both set c as you want and also print out `[a]+[b]= ` and wait for user to finish the question. Code edited to do exactly that.